# My website down again and again due to MySQL failed due to poor optimization in magento

Tags: database, magento, optimization

server provider give this mail :
David F.
June 01, 2016 at 02:28 AM 
Hello,
Please refrain from opening old tickets for new issues as this will delay and confuse your resolution.
I have brought MySQL back up on your server at this time.  MySQL failed due to poor optimization on abc.com, in its database, and the amount of traffic abc.com received.  In a single minute the domain received over a thousand requests.
    First Entry: 01/Jun/2016:12:31:00
     Last Entry: 01/Jun/2016:12:31:570194102 B] 
Lines processed: 0000001042 [196K/0000201010 B]

```
      Total number of unique IP addresses:         41
                 Total number of requests:       1042
   Total number of unique request strings:        196
          Total number of unique referers:         15
       Total number of unique user agents:         28
        Total bandwidth sent in responses:        14M [  15267079B]

   Top 10 requesting IP Addresses based on count:
            COUNT:      313 / 30.04%  IP:  108.179.204.83  HOST: pre.abc.com
            COUNT:      171 / 16.41%  IP:    54.227.18.40  HOST: ec2-54-227-18-40.compute-1.amazonaws.com
            COUNT:      134 / 12.86%  IP:     54.163.6.82  HOST: ec2-54-163-6-82.compute-1.amazonaws.com
            COUNT:      131 / 12.57%  IP:   183.182.87.75  HOST: static-182-87-75.rpnspl.com
            COUNT:      105 / 10.08%  IP:     59.95.57.26  HOST: Unknown Host
            COUNT:       36 / 03.45%  IP:   54.196.238.20  HOST: ec2-54-196-238-20.compute-1.amazonaws.com
            COUNT:       31 / 02.98%  IP:   117.247.235.3  HOST: Unknown Host
            COUNT:       28 / 02.69%  IP:  123.201.52.244  HOST: 244-52-201-123.static.youbroadband.in
            COUNT:        9 / 00.86%  IP:  68.180.228.175  HOST: b110088.yse.yahoo.net
            COUNT:        9 / 00.86%  IP:   45.125.187.42  HOST: Unknown Host

   Top 10 Request Strings:
           Count:      340 / 32.63%     Request: "POST /index.php/api/soap/index/ HTTP/1.1"
           Count:      311 / 29.85%     Request: "GET /index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1 HTTP/1.1"
           Count:       12 / 01.15%     Request: "GET / HTTP/1.1"
           Count:        5 / 00.48%     Request: "GET /media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/260x260/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/f/o/foodprocessor.png HTTP/1.1"
           Count:        5 / 00.48%     Request: "GET /media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/260x260/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/s/p/spray-mop.jpg HTTP/1.1"
           Count:        5 / 00.48%     Request: "GET /media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/260x260/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/4/2/42604_1_.jpg HTTP/1.1"
           Count:        4 / 00.38%     Request: "GET /media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/260x260/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/s/k/sku-700-gkh600sl.jpg HTTP/1.1"
           Count:        4 / 00.38%     Request: "GET /media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/260x260/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/s/k/sku-700-potg19pcr-red.jpg HTTP/1.1"
           Count:        4 / 00.38%     Request: "GET /skin/frontend/sns_simen/default/images/border.png HTTP/1.1"
           Count:        4 / 00.38%     Request: "GET /media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/260x260/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/s/k/sku-700-akh900cb.jpg HTTP/1.1"

   Top 10 User Agents:
           Count:      340 / 32.63%  User Agent: "PHP-SOAP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11"
           Count:      314 / 30.13%  User Agent: "-"
           Count:      131 / 12.57%  User Agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.137 Safari/537.36"
           Count:      105 / 10.08%  User Agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0.2; vivo Y51L Build/LRX22G) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.89 Mobile Safari/537.36"
           Count:       39 / 03.74%  User Agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"
           Count:       34 / 03.26%  User Agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"
           Count:       10 / 00.96%  User Agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0"
           Count:        9 / 00.86%  User Agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Yahoo! Slurp; http://help.yahoo.com/help/us/ysearch/slurp)"
           Count:        9 / 00.86%  User Agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Mobile; Windows Phone 8.1; Android 4.0; ARM; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0; IEMobile/11.0; NOKIA; Lumia 525) like iPhone OS 7_0_3 Mac OS X AppleWebKit/537 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile Safari/537"
           Count:        7 / 00.67%  User Agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0"
```

=====================================================================

I strongly recommend optimizing both the site and the database so that it is less resource intensive or this could occur again.  Additionally you may consider using a Content Delivery Network such as Sitelock or Cloudflare so that less stress is placed on the server during high traffic.

Database: abc_live
+-------------------------------------------------+----------+------------+
|                     Tables                      | Columns  | Total Rows |
+-------------------------------------------------+----------+------------+
| core_url_rewrite                                |       10 |      74108 |
| customer_entity_varchar                         |        5 |      77885 |
| log_url                                         |        3 |     283444 |
| log_url_info                                    |        3 |     283444 |
| log_visitor                                     |        6 |     316794 |
| log_visitor_info                                |        7 |     316794 |
| m_fpc_crawler_url                               |       10 |     504698 |
| m_fpc_log                                       |        4 |    4144330 |
| report_event                                    |        7 |      87849 |
| report_viewed_product_index                     |        6 |      64276 |
| sales_flat_quote_address                        |       69 |     102544 |
| sales_flat_quote_item                           |       54 |      57560 |
| sales_flat_quote_item_option                    |        5 |      78328 |

If you have any further questions or need any further clarification you can always reply to this ticket or reach us 24/7 through our live web chat system ( https://chat.hostgator.com/ ) or our US/Canada toll-free number (866) 96 - GATOR (42867) or our international line 00+1-713-574-5287.

So please help me how to optimize magento database so that site not down by more request.

Comment: This isn't a magento db problem, sorry to tell you. Soap seems to be more most popular connection by far, so its not traffic related, and the amount of traffic you do get is negligible.  Its possible you need a better host, or a fresh install of mysql, it could have been done on an older version, which doesn't support everything Magento needs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?